# how to install two modules related to EXPORT_SYMBOL on beaglebone

Tags: makefile, module, kernel, driver, symbols

I'm writing a beaglebone driver and for this I need two modules: **gpio_module** and **BBG_module** which are related to **EXPORT_SYMBOL**.
In *gpio_module.c* I wrote

```
uint8_t GPIO_device(void)
{}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(GPIO_device);
```

and in *BBG_module.c*

```
extern uint8_t GPIO_device(void);
GPIO_device();
```

added to makefile

```
    obj-m := gpio-module.o BBG_module.o

    ARCH=arm 
    CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
    KERNELDIR=/usr/src/kernels/linux-4.9.82-ti-r102

   
arm_modules:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=`pwd`/dep/Module.symvers
    echo "bulding module for arm architecture:"
```

by running the **make** command, I got two *.ko* files and a *Module.symvers* dependency file with all EXPORT_SYMBOLs.

- Do I need to send the *Module.symvers* to the beaglebone too?
- Or add something to the makefile and is `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=`pwd`/dep/Module.symvers` needed

I'm a beginner and would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example Makefile that combines several modules into one:

```
obj-m := mymodule.o

mymodule-objs := gpio_module.o adc_module.o uart_module.o crc.o

ccflags-y := -I$(src)/include

gpio_module-objs := GPIO_module.o
adc_module-objs := ADC_module.o
uart_module-objs := UART_module.o

ARCH=arm 
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-   
KERNELDIR=~/linux
   
arm_modules:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

This Makefile combines several modules into a single module, `mymodule.o`, while specifying which source files are needed for each module. It also includes the `-I$(src)/include` flag to search for header files. Please make sure the order of the modules matches the requirements of the dependencies in your project. this despite the fact that `GPIO_module.o ADC_module.o` contain `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, which are used in `UART_module`